# how to can i display mobile number in 123-456-7890 format in textfield

Tags: iphone

i need to enter mobile number in a text field.

i need to display mobile number like this format 123-456-7890.

for eg: 1234567890 is my mobile number,while am entering this mobile number in text field,

for first 3 digits i need to place -,after 3 digits again i need to place -.

if i enter 123 then automatically place - in text field,after 456 place ,no need of placing for further 4 digits.

similar to displaying text in currency format.

but while getting text from that text field i need to get mobile number no need of - like 1234567890,not 123-456-7890.

i think my question is quite clear now,let me add comment if is not.

Thank u in advance.

Comment: Please rephrase your question or give some example because it is not clear what you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just to clarify: As a user enters a phone number into a UITextField, you would like it to automatically insert dashes in the proper places.

The answer is in using the UITextFieldDelegate protocol.

1) Set your controller object as a delegate for the UITextField.

2) You'll find the following method in the protocol:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

This method is called every time a character change occurs in the text field.

3) How robust you want your implementation to be is up to you. You could simply do a count of the current characters and insert dashes after 3 and 6 characters. It would be wise to also reject any non-numeric characters.

Here is a sample implementation. We basically take over the field editing manually - Inserting dashes after the appropriate string lengths and making sure the user can only enter numbers:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSCharacterSet *numSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789-"];
    NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    int charCount = [newString length];

    if ([newString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[numSet invertedSet]].location != NSNotFound
        || [string rangeOfString:@"-"].location != NSNotFound
        || charCount > 12) {
        return NO;
    }

    if (charCount == 3 || charCount == 7) {
        newString = [newString stringByAppendingString:@"-"];
    }

    textField.text = newString;

    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Thank u  Matthew Mc Googan,If i use this when i there is case the user enter mistake,if he want's remove then - symbol is not removed.i mean 123-456-7890 in this number, upto 123-456- is removed - is not removed,I am very thankful if i got solution for this also

Comment: Yeah, @MaheshBabu is right. You need to add the following to the top of function: `if ([string isEqualToString:@""]) { return YES; }`

Comment: Is there a way to deal with backspace? When you try to delete a dash it adds another one because it's at that character count for appending a dash.

Answer (score 4):

Updated Matthew McGoogan's code : This works fine with back space also..

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string { if (textField.tag == 8) {           
        NSCharacterSet *numSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789-"];
        NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
        int charCount = [newString length];

        if (charCount == 3 || charCount == 7) {
            if ([string isEqualToString:@""]){
                return YES;
            }else{
                newString = [newString stringByAppendingString:@"-"];
            }
        }

        if (charCount == 4 || charCount == 8) {
            if (![string isEqualToString:@"-"]){
                newString = [newString substringToIndex:[newString length]-1];
                newString = [newString stringByAppendingString:@"-"];
            }
        }

        if ([newString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[numSet invertedSet]].location != NSNotFound
            || [string rangeOfString:@"-"].location != NSNotFound
            || charCount > 12) {
            return NO;
        }

        textField.text = newString;
    return NO;
}    
return YES;}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used Matthews post above as a base.

This will format as so: (444) 444-4444

It also handles backspaces, unlike the answer above.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    if(textField == _txtPhone1 || textField == _txtPhone2 || textField == _txtPhone3 || textField == _txtPhone4)
    {

        NSCharacterSet *numSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789-() "];
        NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
        int charCount = [newString length];
        if ([newString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[numSet invertedSet]].location != NSNotFound
            || [string rangeOfString:@")"].location != NSNotFound
            || [string rangeOfString:@"("].location != NSNotFound
            || [string rangeOfString:@"-"].location != NSNotFound
            || charCount > 14) {
            return NO;
        }
        if (![string isEqualToString:@""])
        {
            if (charCount == 1)
            {
                newString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@", newString];
            }
            else if(charCount == 4)
            {
                newString = [newString stringByAppendingString:@") "];
            }
            else if(charCount == 5)
            {
                newString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@) %@", [newString substringToIndex:4], [newString substringFromIndex:4]];
            }
            else if(charCount == 6)
            {
                newString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [newString substringToIndex:5], [newString substringFromIndex:5]];
            }

            else if (charCount == 9)
            {
                newString = [newString stringByAppendingString:@"-"];
            }
            else if(charCount == 10)
            {
                newString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@", [newString substringToIndex:9], [newString substringFromIndex:9]];
            }
        }
        textField.text = newString;
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
NSString* number = [textField.text  stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"-" withString: @""];
```

Comment: You might want to double check the question, bro.