# IS it possible to customize the uitextfield so that it could look like on the picture

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I have an issue - I need to customize the uitextfield like this:

[image]

Is it possible to do it???? And if yes, so how???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes something like that would be possible. If you are using IB for instance you can set the style of a `UITextField` as follows:

[image]

By setting the text field's `Borders Style` property you can even do something as simple as placing a `UIImageView` behind this text field so achieve the desired effect.

Comment: This picture is from the web form. I have to create something like this, in order to make the UI more user friendly. So it shouldn't be like a picture, it should be like javascript form :)

Answer (score 2):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163499/how-to-can-i-display-mobile-number-in-123-456-7890-format-in-textfield) can be solution for your problem. It user different format, try to replace it from number format that you want